# Adding a "entered by" field to crud operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-view-controller

I have a simple CRUD app in .net core with an Admin role and the rest of the users are normal users with no role. I wanted to make the Index of the crud data have the user next to each input that submitted the data while signed in. So say user1@app.com entered data into the database - I want their email to show up next to that data entry in the Index view. That way every user can have their own data tracked.

I have been searching questions and googling forever and maybe I just don't know how to word it correctly. If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Something like below..

| Food item | Price | Entered by |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1.00 | user1@app.com |
| Pear | 2.00 | user2@app.com |

Comment: Aside: For historical purposes an email address is hardly a stable, unique identifier.

Comment: Do you already have EnteredBy column in the table? How are you currently saving values for other columns? Did you try writing and code for this? Please share the code if you have written anything.

Comment: I have just regular getters and setters for Food Item and Price in my Model class and they are also in my SQL database. When those options are created it passes it to the view in the Index Page. 
I would enter a "EnteredBy" in my Model but I am not sure how to make it equal the user that is currently signed in that adds a record to the Create option.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When registering with a record with the following code, you can obtain and save the user email.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```